# When executing query that is after Declare End part is giving me error

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am running a query, but before that, I am executing a procedure from the database that changes the session access for the user that executes the query.

The Begin End part and the execution of the procedure call is executed just fine but when it tries to execute the select query it gives me the error ORA-06550 PLS 00103: Encountered the symbol WITH.

Like i am not able to execute the procedure call and then execute the select statement for some reason.

Please advise.

The initial call of the code is

```
Begin
 util.change_institutions(a_instition => 900);
End;

With Balance as ( Select * from cbalances where method=100),
User as ( select * from users where user_id = 10132)

Select * from Balance b
Full Join User u  on u.Serno=b.Serno;
```

I need this to be execute in a single session. Any ideas that might help me execute this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please provide a `'/'` after PL/SQL Block;

Every PL/SQL Statement, only when `'/'` is given is actually flushed to the database engine.

```
Begin
 util.change_institutions(a_instition => 900);
End;
/

With Balance as ( Select * from cbalances where method=100),
User as ( select * from users where user_id = 10132)
Select * from Balance b
Full Join User u  on u.Serno=b.Serno;
```

Comment: +1 It might also be worth mentioning that you may have fixed another issue by removing the blank line.  By default SQL*Plus does not accept blank lines in SQL statements.

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback. The issue is resolved by having the / under the End; line.